# asp.net mvc stop textbox value from updating from previous textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, auto-populate

I have an MVC registration model and form that captures: User Name, Full Name, Email and Password.

When I run the form and enter the User Name and hit tab to goto the Full Name textbox, the Full Name textbox is auto-populating with the value from the User Name texbox...  I'm not sure why this is happening?  Any suggestions on what I can dig into to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions that could be doing this? It also could be an autofill feature baked into the browser itself.

Comment: Thank you Lews for the kick in the right direction.  It was indeed an 'autofill' feature.  Tested the app on another browser and it functions as it should.